# Concatenation of strings not working - Javascript

Tags: javascript, concatenation

In this program, I'm generating a random word, getting the input of the user and printing the users' inputted letters in an alert box if the letter exists in the word.

This is where I generate a random word.

```
var words = ['Quaffle', 'Bludger', 'Pensieve', 'Harry', 'Lupin', 
'Butterbeer', 'Polyjuice', 'Patronus', 'Horcrux', 'Voldemort'];

function getRandomWord(){
 randomWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random()* words.length)]; 
 wordlength = randomWord.length;
}
```

And this is function where I get the guess of the user and print it in an alert box along with the correct letters.

```
function getGuess(){
   if(event.keyCode == 13) {
     letterGuessed = document.getElementById("inputfield").value;
     document.getElementById("inputfield").value = null;
     alert(randomWord);
     alert(letterGuessed);
     r = randomWord.includes(letterGuessed);

     if(r == true){
        correctletters='';
        correctletters = correctletters + letterGuessed;
        alert(correctletters);
    }
  }
}
```

My problem here is that the correct letter guessed does not concatenate in `correctletters` variable. I'm only getting one character which is the `letterguessed` variable in the alert box. I even tried using `concat`, but I get the same result. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `correctletters=''; correctletters = correctletters + letterGuessed;` what you're basically doing here is `correctletters = letterGuessed` since you're emptying `correctletters` every time.

Comment: But if I remove `correctletters = ' ';` the alert box doesn't come at all despite typing the right letter.

Comment: The questions is not clear what do you mean by `getting the input of the user and printing the users' inputted letters in an alert box if the letter exists in the word.` and which word?

Comment: Then `correctletters` isn't declared in the right place or isn't in scope. Which is a bit hard to tell without seeing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @brk a random word I generate. I will post the whole code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, each time you are about to add a new letter, you are resetting the concatenated letters back to an empty string before concatenating the new one.

You should move the following line to somewhere at the initialization logic where you first generate the random word (outside the `getGuess` function:

```
correctletters='';
```

Comment: Yes this worked. Thanks! I moved the `correctletters = ' ';` just below the `var words` where I initialized the words.